# Is there a proper way to modify the contents of a SWT window based on a button press?

Tags: java, swt

The window in "small" mode only has a line of text, a progress bar, open "logs", and a cancel button. When you press the open "logs" button, it should show a windows with the same contents above except it changes to a close "logs" button, and the logs show up.

I have a piece of code below that doesn't work but as far as I know - should. Before I made this code, I made 2 versions of the window that interchange being open when you press the open/close "logs". I didn't like that it had to close the old window and open a new one.

Is there a better way to do this besides the malfunctioning code below?

The issue here is that, it works for 0.1 seconds then it loops changing between state 1 then state 2. It then says "not responding" after about 5 seconds.

```
package main;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;

public class ProcessBar {

    protected Shell shlApplicationName = new Shell();
    private boolean logs = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBar window = new ProcessBar();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        launch();
        shlApplicationName.open();
        shlApplicationName.layout();
        while (!shlApplicationName.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
    
    Label lblGeneratingWhat = new Label(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Button btnCancel = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Text text = new Text(shlApplicationName, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Button btnLogs = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    
    private void launch() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setText("Application Name");
        if (logs) {
            bigSizes();
        }else {
            smallContents();
        }
        
    }
    
    private void bigSizes() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setSize(450, 247);

        lblGeneratingWhat.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 15);
        lblGeneratingWhat.setText("Generating What?");

        progressBar.setBounds(10, 31, 414, 29);

        btnCancel.setBounds(349, 173, 75, 25);
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");

        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBounds(10, 66, 333, 132);
        
        btnLogs.setBounds(349, 142, 75, 25);
        btnLogs.setText("Logs");
        
        btnLogs.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                logs = !logs;
                launch();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void smallContents() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setSize(450, 138);
        
        lblGeneratingWhat.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 15);
        lblGeneratingWhat.setText("Generating What?");
        
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 31, 414, 29);
        
        btnCancel.setBounds(349, 66, 75, 25);
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        
        text.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        
        btnLogs.setBounds(268, 66, 75, 25);
        btnLogs.setText("Logs");
        
        btnLogs.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                logs = !logs;
                launch();
            }
        });
        

    }
}
```

Edit: This new piece of code works much better BUT it gets worse the more times you press between the "logs" button.

It works normally the first 2 times you open the logs, then close it. After that, it starts glitching the same way as the code above with an ever increasing time each press.

```
package main;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;

public class ProcessBar {

    protected Shell shlApplicationName = new Shell();
    private boolean logs = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBar window = new ProcessBar();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        launch();
        shlApplicationName.open();
        shlApplicationName.layout();
        while (!shlApplicationName.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
    
    Label lblGeneratingWhat = new Label(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Button btnCancel = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Text text = new Text(shlApplicationName, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Button btnLogs = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Button btn2Logs = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    
    private void launch() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setText("Application Name");
        if (logs) {
            bigSizes();
        }else {
            smallContents();
        }
        
        
    }
    
    private void bigSizes() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setSize(450, 247);

        lblGeneratingWhat.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 15);
        lblGeneratingWhat.setText("Generating Whatdog?");

        progressBar.setBounds(10, 31, 414, 29);

        btnCancel.setBounds(349, 173, 75, 25);
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");

        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBounds(10, 66, 333, 132);
        
        btnLogs.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        
        btn2Logs.setBounds(349, 142, 75, 25);
        btn2Logs.setText("Logs");
        
        btn2Logs.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                logs = !logs;
                launch();
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void smallContents() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setSize(450, 138);
        
        lblGeneratingWhat.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 15);
        lblGeneratingWhat.setText("Generating What?");
        
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 31, 414, 29);
        
        btnCancel.setBounds(349, 66, 75, 25);
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        
        text.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        
        btn2Logs.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        
        btnLogs.setBounds(268, 66, 75, 25);
        btnLogs.setText("Logs");
        
        btnLogs.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                logs = !logs;
                launch();
            }
        });
        

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the mouseDown event listener. I still don't know what the issue here is

Comment: Use `addSelectionListener` on a button to handle the click.

Comment: Separately always use Layouts rather than setBounds. setBounds will give poor results if different fonts are used or on a different platform. [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)

Comment: You are adding additional mouse listeners each time you switch - they are all called. Add a single selection listener when the controls are created. Also use `setVisible` to hide things rather than `setBounds` with zeros.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the explanation. It glossed over my head that it makes a new MouseAdapter each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I fixed it.

Greg-449 gave suggestions as to how to fix the problem in the comments of the question. Here is how I quote on quote "fixed" it.

Code:

```
package main;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;

public class ProcessBar {

    protected Shell shlApplicationName = new Shell();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBar window = new ProcessBar();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        prelaunch();
        shlApplicationName.open();
        shlApplicationName.layout();
        while (!shlApplicationName.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
    
    Label lblGeneratingWhat = new Label(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Button btnCancel = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    Text text = new Text(shlApplicationName, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    
    Button btnLogs = new Button(shlApplicationName, SWT.NONE);
    private boolean logs = false;

    private void prelaunch() {
        
        launch();
        
        btnLogs.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                logs = !logs;
                launch();
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    private void launch() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setText("Application Name");
        
        if (logs) {
            bigSizes();
        }else {
            smallContents();
        }   
        
    }
    
    private void bigSizes() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setSize(450, 247);

        lblGeneratingWhat.setText("Generating Whatdog?");

        progressBar.setBounds(10, 31, 414, 29);

        btnCancel.setBounds(349, 173, 75, 25);

        text.setVisible(true);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBounds(10, 66, 333, 132);
        
        btnLogs.setBounds(349, 142, 75, 25);
        
        
    }
    
    private void smallContents() {
        
        shlApplicationName.setSize(450, 138);
        
        lblGeneratingWhat.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 15);
        lblGeneratingWhat.setText("Generating What?");
        
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 31, 414, 29);
        
        btnCancel.setBounds(349, 66, 75, 25);
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        
        text.setVisible(false);

        btnLogs.setBounds(268, 66, 75, 25);
        btnLogs.setText("Logs");
        


    }
}
```

The difference is I made sure to NOT create a new *mouselistener* listening to the same button. Instead of (psuedocode)

```
function launch{
   create mouse listener
      if logs is true then open logs, else open no logs version
      open launch

}
```

I turned it into: (psuedocode)

```
function prelaunch{
   create mouse listener
   open launch
}

function launch{
   if logs is true then open logs, else open no logs version
      open launch
}
```

The flickering issue happens because a new mouse listener is called which flips the boolean and relaunches the app. In my first iteration of the code, this cause a loop of new mouse listeners being created WHILE im pressing the button.

On the second iteration (the Edit on the question) of the code, I made it so each "change" only creates one new mouse listener. This meant that for the first 2 window changes, nothing really happened as the mouse listeners were both only at 1 instance. After two uses, there are more mouse listeners that was required, so it started flickering again.

Thank you!